# Returning record inserted successfully in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, n-tier-architecture, 3-tier

In my DAL I have the following:

```
DB.ExecuteNonQuery(DBCommand);
```

then in my BLL I have the following:

```
DAL.data.insertticket(a);
```

and then in my presentation layer I have:

```
DAL.collection cobj = new collection();
BLL.business bobj = new business();
bobj.insertticket(cobj);
```

How do I check if the record was inserted in the database and then get my lbl to fade in and disappear after 2 seconds?

```
<asp:Label ID="lblUpdatedMessage" runat="server" 
           Text="Ticket Updated"></asp:Label>
```

I thought about doing the following in my presentation layer:

```
if (DAL.data.insertticket(a) == true) {
    lblUpdatedMessage.Visible = true;
}
```

But I get an error saying:

> The name 'a' does not exist in the current context

Comment: return a value from the database command, true if it was successful or false if not.

Comment: @PriceCheaperton where you defined 'a'?

Comment: @shariqueansari it is defined in the DAL

Comment: This `DB.ExecuteNonQuery(DBCommand)` statement will return you no of `rows affected`, just return it to the `PL`, and in your `PL` just verify no of `rows affected is > 0` then `lblUpdatedMessage.Visible = true;`

Comment: You ask about how to know if a record has been inserted but you complain about an error totally unrelated to the first problem. Could you explain better what is your real problem?

Comment: @Steve its related because its stopping me from doing a sucess check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an integer value representing the number of records modified/deleted/inserted by the executing query. It is zero if the insert fails, otherwise is greater than zero (depending on how many rows are affected by the call). All you need to do is returning that value up to the call chain until you could handle it in your presentation layer.

And do not just jump from the presentation layer directly to the data layer.  This invalidates totally the layer structure that you have built:

DATALAYER

```
int InsertObject(yourValidObjectInstance)
{
    .... code to prepare the command to be executed ...

    // returns 0 if no record has been added (failure)
    int recordsAffected = DB.ExecuteNonQuery(DBCommand);
    return recordAffected;
}
```

BUSINESS LAYER

```
... code that checks if your object follows the business rules 
... and the validity of your object

int records = DAL.InsertObject(yourValidObject);
// True if you have inserted your records
return (record > 0);
```

PRESENTATION LAYER

```
if(BusinessLayer.AddObject(yourValidObject))
   // execute your presentation code.....
```

Comment: I understand the DAL and BLL parts but bit stuck on the PL i have put:            `if BLL.business(bobj.insertticket(a)){ }` but getting an error

Comment: `'BLL.business' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context`

Comment: I have given a pseudocode of the flow to follow, Of course you need to instantiate the correct classes needed to complete the communication. For example, if your Business Layer has a class named `TicketBLL` then you need a `TicketBLL ticket = new Ticket();` and call the method that inserts the ticket using the DAL classes. But perhaps it is better if you post a new question with the exact code used in the Business and Data Layers